# Parametric solution of a multiple integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, exponential-function

Let $b$ and $a_i, i = 1,2,3,...,  n$ be positive real numbers such that

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ldots \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-b x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\ldots x_1^{a_2}} dx_1 dx_2 \ldots dx_n = 1.
$$

I am looking for an expression of $b$ in terms of $a_i$.

I have obtained the solution for $i=1$ which is as follows. If

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-b x^a} dx = 1
$$
then
$$
b = \Gamma \Big(1+\frac{1}{a}\Big)^a.
$$

Thus for all $a \ge 0$,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{a})^a x^a} = 1.
$$

Comment: notice your exponential's argument differs from what Ron Gordon expects you mean. Is that the only typo?

Comment: @James: I think there is a difference. Please refer to my comment on Ron's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure under what conditions this integral even converges.  Let's write the integral as follows:

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx_1 \, \int_0^{\infty} dx_2 \,\cdots \int_0^{\infty} dx_n \,e^{-b x_1^{a_1} x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_n^{a_n}}$$

Note that, in evaluating the integral over $x_n$, we may treat everything else as a constant, so you end up with an integral much like the one you already evaluated.  That is, consider the result

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \, e^{-b x^a} = b^{-1/a} \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)$$

Then the above multiple integral may be written as

$$b^{-1/a_n} \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right) \int_0^{\infty} dx_1 \,x_1^{-a_1/a_n}\, \int_0^{\infty} dx_2 \,x_2^{-a_2/a_n}\,\cdots \int_0^{\infty} dx_{n-1} \, x_{n-1}^{-a_{n-1}/a_n}$$

It is unclear to me how any of the above integrals will converge.

Comment: I am not able to follow the equation in the middle. As per my condition, the value of $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-bx^a}dx$ should be 1 and not $b^{-1/a}\Gamma(1+1/a)$.

Comment: @user60930: yes, but in general, that is the value of the integral.  You are specifying that it be equal to one in that case; set my expression to one and you recover your expression for $b$.  But you also want the value of the multiple integral to be one, and given that the integral doesn't seem to converge, there is no way you can set it to one.

Comment: OK i got what you are saying. Just to clarify, in case of the multiple integral, I do not need the individual $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-bx_1^{a_1}}$ to be equal to 1. Only the combined multiple should be equal to 1. However as you said, I am not sure about the convergence conditions.

Comment: @user60930: *I do not need the individual <integrals> to be equal to 1. Only the combined multiple should be equal to 1.*  Yes, I agree, that's what I was trying to say.